# how to install posix in php

Tags: php, posix

POSIX does not appear when I run `php -m cmd`, however, I see it from the `phpinfo()` `–enable-posix=shared` on Linux with Plesk 9.

Basically, I can't use `posix_*()` functions as described at 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.posix.php

this shows doesn't exists:

```
if (function_exists('posix_getuid')) {
    echo "posix_getuid available";
} else {
    echo "posix_getuid not available"; // this prints in my server.
}
```

Could someone show me how to install it? Thank you.

```
[PHP Modules]
bz2
calendar
ctype
curl
date
dbase
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
geoip
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
imap
ionCube Loader
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
memcache
mhash
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
sqlite
standard
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
yum install php-process
```

This package enables php-posix.

Comment: BTW - if you're using a typical amazon AMI you will want this package for System_Daemon in pear to work correctly.

Comment: The php-process package name depends on your running php version such as `php56w-process.x86_64`, `php71w-process.x86_64`.

Answer (score 4):

While resolved, the original problem would seem to be that `posix_getpwuid` is not supported on Windows:

from: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-getpwuid.php

On Windows, `posix_getpwuid()` is not implemented

- if you just want the username of the current user, you can use `get_current_user()`.
- To properly get the running user, test if `function_exists('posix_getpwuid')` and if not, assume you're running on Windows and call `getenv('USERNAME')`.

Comment: Your answer is completely unrelated to the question, I think. The problem occurred on Linux, and the used function was a different one.

Answer (score 1):

In openSUSE use command `zypper install php-posix` for installing php-process for using php function `posix_getuid`